# WordPress wp_insert_post function automatically converts the post_name value into lower case

Tags: wordpress

I have a following code and it is so annoying that post_name is automatically converted to lowercase.

```
$post = array(
    'post_name'    => 'SampleWord',
    ),
);
// assume $post have other necessary fields as well
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, true );
```

When I check the post_name after above code it returns `'sampleword'`.
I've checked the documentation of `wp_insert_post` and it mentioned `'post_name'` field would be sanitized.
But converting to lowercase characters is not about sanitization.
And how to prevent it?

Comment: you can look at the `wp_unique_post_slug` filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $arg = array(
    'post_name'    => 'SampleWord',
    'post_title' => 'I Have CAPS',
    );
// assume $post have other necessary fields as well
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $arg, true );
```

That's an easy one to confuse because of the names but post_name is really the slug and [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) warns you it'll sanitize it (as you noted) but [sanitize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) does also lowercase things.

Try the post_title addition above and see if it works out for you.

Comment: although we specify post_title it still converts to lowercase

Comment: I think you've got something else going on then. I tested this revised code and it's working with caps for sure.

Comment: Either a filter or  there is CSS that uses `text-transform: lowercase;`

Answer (score 1):

By default the post name is formatted and converted to lower-cased by the filter sanitize_title which hooks into sanitize_title_with_dashes(). As a solution you can replace the filter and omit the lower-case component.

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'custom_sanitize_title', 10, 3 );
function custom_sanitize_title( $title ) {

    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    $title = remove_accents($title);
    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
            if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
                    $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
            }
            $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
    }

    // Prevent lower case 
    // $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```